# How do I expand wildcards in Python

Tags: python

Python doesn't accept paths like '~/Pictures'

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Pictures'
```

How can I get Python to expand these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) (and maybe [`os.path.expandvars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars)).